# Проблема с отладкой в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

У меня есть рабочее приложение на Java. Я ставлю точку останова, запускаю отладку и получаю белый экран на эмуляторе и на девайсе, хотя есть элементы в xml, которые должны отобразиться.

Comment: Экран будет сформирован только после onResume. Возможно вы ставите точки в onCreate?

Comment: Да, я ставлю точки в onCreate. В моем коде нет onResume; при создании проекта он не появляется автоматически.

Comment: onResume - это метод из жизненного цикла активити. Чтобы он появился его надо переопределить Ctrl + O, но сам он вам доступ к интерфейсу не даст, поскольку он должен завершиться. Если нужно продебажить какой-то метод, повесте его на какое либо событие (например нажатие кнопки) или используйте тестирование